# Custom Meta Fields that are Echo'd are removed on post update?

Tags: post-meta

I have a custom front-end post page that lets users submit posts via a front-end form.

It seems to work fine and I then have a custom php page that displays the contents of said post.

This php page has some basic echo's such as:

```
   <?php echo wpautop(get_the_content()); ?>

   <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field', true ); ?>
```

And so on.

My issue is, if I update a post to ammend something, the "get_post_meta" echos are being removed on update. get_the_content seems to be fine but every custom field seems to be removed on the page once it's updated (although the actual custom fields remain attached to the post).

Any ideas?

Comment: please share the url

Comment: On this page, the deck list is inserted as a custom-field, along with the "deck information" table. The description wrote is the get_the_content part. 
So if I use wordpress to edit the page and for example add something to the deck list custom field, it removes both the deck list and deck information custom fields on post update.
I'm new to using custom templates so I could be doing something very wrong.
Here is an example of one of the created pages: https://ygoprodeck.com/arkana/

Comment: While you open a post, all deck infrormation is showing or not in back panel.

Comment: Yeah all the information is showing on the post in the back panel (under "Custom Fields"). It's like when I update the page using edit post it just calls the_content() which doesn't have my echo'd custom fields anymore.

Comment: Ok so I see what's happening. When a post is published from the front-end it's using deck-content-single.php but if I edit that post it changes to use content-single.php instead. Hmmmm.

Comment: Great :) Happy Coding!